# Run job at boot and on a schedule from same crontab

Tags: cron

I have a process that I need to run on boot and periodically.

I've created a file for it in `/etc/cron.d/`. Is there a way for me to specify that I want `@reboot 0,30 * * * *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two entries in your crontab (or two files, whichever you prefer).  You can't combine those.